# function = not return value(integer) but is return date (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have error in using `Excel Formula`

> Error:
>
> On i am enter `=Data!G5`
>
> ```
> |----- |
> | G5   |
> |----- |
> | 135  |
> ```
>
> is return date for example `5/18/1900`

**What's the error ? please help me**

Comment: Are you sure that 135 is returning 5/18/1900 and not 5/14/1900?

Comment: is return random date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the formula cell to **Number**

[image]

Comment: i am cell it but is return date !! i am check in the sheet Data i am test =G5 is return the number that is okay but if i am use it in another sheet isn't working. why isn't working.

Comment: @HaMzADeveloper  See my example in the answer.

Comment: @Gray's Student Thank You !